# Ошибка при запуске любого образа "Error in supR3HardNtChildWaitFor"

Tags: virtualbox

Windows 7 (64)
Антивирус Windows Defender
VirtualBox 5.0.14.
Часть логов:

```
12a8.748: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Opening vboxdrv stub...
12a8.748: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Restoring LdrInitializeThunk...
12a8.748: supR3HardenedVmProcessInit: Returning to LdrInitializeThunk...
12a8.748: Registered Dll notification callback with NTDLL.
12a8.748: supHardenedWinVerifyImageByHandle: -> 22900 (\Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll)
12a8.748: supR3HardenedWinVerifyCacheInsert: \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll
12a8.748: supR3HardenedMonitor_LdrLoadDll: pName=C:\Windows\system32\kernel32.dll (Input=kernel32.dll, rcNtResolve=0xc0150008) *pfFlags=0xffffffff pwszSearchPath=0000000000000000:<flags> [calling]
12a8.748: supR3HardenedScreenImage/NtCreateSection: cache hit (Unknown Status 22900 (0x5974)) on \Device\HarddiskVolume4\Windows\System32\kernel32.dll [lacks WinVerifyTrust]
884.176c: Error (rc=258):
884.176c: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
884.176c: Error 258 in supR3HardNtChildWaitFor! (enmWhat=5)
884.176c: Timed out after 60001 ms waiting for child request #1 (CloseEvents).
```

Answer (score 3):

КриптоПро на машине стоит?

Попробуйте добавить ветку в реестр и туда строковый параметр. После добавления перезагрузиться.

`[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\CProExclude\VirtualBox]
"FileName"="VirtualBox.exe"`

Comment: [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\SessionManager\CProExclude\VirtualBox] "FileName"="VirtualBox.exe" Почему-то при установке такая строчка не добавляется в реестр, но она нужна.